# Logging into website with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to www.boiteajeux.net using the Python (2.7) requests module, but don't seem to be having much luck. This is what I have so far:

```
payload = {
    'pAction': 'login',
    'username': 'myUsername',
    'password': 'myPassword'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('http://boiteajeux.net/gestion.php', data=payload)
    [more code attempting to reach part of the site that requires me to be logged in]
```

I found the form details by looking at the page source:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="./gestion.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="pAction" value="login">
    <label for="username">Login</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" size="15" class="clInput">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="15" class="clInput">
    <label for="autologin">Log on auto</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="autologin">
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="btn">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm not sure whether I've translated that correctly into the payload. I think the website is just redirecting me to the home page. I've tried searching for text (like my username) that I know should appear if I've logged in correctly but couldn't find it.

I know there have been similar questions to this, and I have read them, but I still haven't been able to crack it.

Comment: I think you still have to send hidden values, even if theyre empty. Press f12 and open the network tabs on either IE or chrome and then perform the login via the browser so you can see exactly what is send.

Comment: I don't see any errors here.  How do you know your attempt is failing? What status code are you getting from the remote server? Is the server providing you with any useful error messages?

Comment: Typically requests uses an "auth" keyword for user authentification from my understanding.

Have you tried the following:
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))

||| (Link to authentification in requests) http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: @ Thomas Wagenaar, I did what you suggested and I found what was sent. It was basically what I've already got in my payload except for a couple of other items. I've added those too now, but still no luck.

Comment: @ larsks, I am not getting any error messages. I don't know how to access the status code from the remote server. I know I am failing because I can't find any of the content I'd expect once logged in.